# Pythonic way to match a string if contained in a set of strings

Tags: python, string

I am trying to match names by using the first, second, and last names, either in the correct order or not, using all of them or not. So far I've got this code and it sort of works, but I think it's not the right way of doing it. Do you know another way of doing this?

The names in the data set look like this:

```
name = 'DAVID SCOTT MUSTAIN'
```

What I want is to match that name if I search for `'DAVID'`, `'MUSTAIN SCOTT'`, `'SCOTT DAVID'`, etc..
The function I got so far looks like this:

```
def search_name(somename):   
    for full_name in some_dataset:
        if set(somename.upper().split()).issubset(full_name.split()):
            print('match:', full_name)
```

If I input something like `'DAV'` or `'SCOT'`, this will not match anything. How should I proceed in order to make a match even with incomplete names? If I split 
 the names into single letters it will match every name with those letters without checking the order of the letters.

Comment: It sounds like a [suffix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) could be interesting to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `any` to check if any name in `somename` is a subset of any of the names in `full_name`

```
def search_name(somename):   
    for full_name in some_dataset:
        if any(n.upper() in fn for n in somename.split() for fn in full_name.split()):
            print('match:', full_name)
```

---

And here is an example using `sum` and a dictionary to pick the name with the most matches:

```
def search_name(somename):  
    matches = {} 
    for full_name in some_dataset:
        matches[full_name] = sum(1 for n in somename.split() for fn in full_name.split() if n.upper() in fn)
    best_matches = [k for k,v in matches.items() if v == max(matches.values()) if v != 0]
    for match in best_matches: 
        print('match:', match)
```

I'm sure there are better ways to write this function but i'm very sleep deprived..
As for your second question perhaps you could print/return all the items in the `best_matches` list?

Comment: this match incomplete names but if i input 'DAVID SCOTT' it matches all 'SCOTT's even if they are not 'DAVID's

Comment: I see. In that case usre the `sum` function and print the name that has the most matches ( if any )

Comment: I have an idea of what you meant but im not really sure how to implement it, could you add it to the answer?(sorry for the troubles), also, what happen if there are two 'DAVID SCOTT' with different last names? assuming the names have no index number to store and then look for it, they will have the same *match likelyhood* so if i store the max likelyhood it will overwrite the last one and if i store the likelyhood in a collection i have no way of searching for those names later.

Comment: Thanks for this approaching, i was able to solve my second question by adding that `best_matches` dont match anything if `max` is 0, and simply iterate over `best_matches` and print them.

Comment: Yes, that's a good idea, there is no need to have items with 0 score in the `best_matches` list. I approved your edit.

Answer (score 1):

I made a little function that use more statements

```
def search_name(name, toSearch, num = 2):
    found = []
    for word in name.split():
        search = word[:num]
        for letter in word[num:]:
            search += letter
            isThere = [data for data in toSearch.split() if data in search]
            if isThere:
                found += isThere
                break
    return len(toSearch.split()) == len(found)

name = 'DAVID SCOTT MUSTAIN'
if search_name(name,'TA'):
    print(name)
else:
    print('Nothing')
```

You want this ?

Comment: I tested with an unordered string to search and it works, can you explain me better the problem, maybe with a code ?

Comment: I encountered that it will not match with every combination, im assuming its for the `number` argument, if i try to match `'TA'`, it doesnt match the name. EDIT: i deleted my last comment because it was not what i meant, i messed up with the words.

Comment: I edit the answer, I change the line where I search the matches, test the code

Comment: it works now, thanks!. i gave you an upvote to send your answer up because is useful and solves the problem, however i accepted t.m's answer because i find it more elegant and readable

Comment: No problem, t.m's answer is more pythonic because it use tools that Python gives and you need it. My answer is more algorithmic no ? haha Saludos !

Answer (score 0):

I might use

```
if full_name in somename and not set(full_name.split()) - set(someone.split())
```

to see if its a substring and it contains no extra short names.